# How to override adminhtml template file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template, overrides

I want to override one adminhtml template file located at /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml

What steps i need to follow?

Answer (score 2):

**You Cannot Override Admin Files Directly In Your Theme. You Need Custom Module For Overriding Admin Files OR Use Existing Custom Module.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="column_name">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body></page>
```

Copy original file into following location
Vendor/Module/sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml

Comment: i dont need to edit anything in this??? in which xml file i need to add this code?

Comment: Change vendor name and module name as per  your vendor and module